# Password-protect file/folder on MacOS

Tags: macos, security

I want to create an encrypted file containing some important passwords. Ideally, I would be able to open that file in a plaintext editor and edit passwords just like I would with any other plaintext file.

I've seen different suggestions to create an encrypted disk image for the folder containing the password file to be encrypted. However, I'd have to re-create that disk image every time I wanted to edit the password file, which seems excessive.

This is my file, `secrets.yaml`:

```
google.com:
  username: mygoogleusername
  password: mygooglepassword
facebook.com:
  username: myfacebookusername
  password: myfacebookpassword
```

How can I password-protect this file? Is it sufficient to run something like `chmod 600 secrets.yaml` (i.e. assign read-write to the owner of the file only)?

Comment: If you are the only user with Administrator rights on that Mac, it should be enough to keep that file somewhere in your user's home directory. Even if there more users on system, they can not read each other's home directories AFAIK unless they have administrator rights. However, I would use 1Passoword's Secure Notes feature for such requirement if there is no need to read that YML file from outside.

Comment: macOS supports read/write encrypted disk images. From Disk Utility, choose File -> New Image -> Blank Image and make sure encryption is on and the image format is read/write.

Comment: I'd use the "sparse disk image" format instead of plain read/write. It's also writable, but only takes up the space actually used for files, so you can format it as a big disk, but it'll actually take much less space. The formatted size is effectively a maximum size, not the actual size.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use tools for individual file encryption, like AxCrypt. It can do 128, 256-bit encryption for an individual file of any kind, by setting a key as you expect, and only you can open the file.

[AxCrypt](http://axcrypt.net/information/features/)